# Discriminant of Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, parallelization, polynomials

I'm doing a calculation which finds the characteristic polynomial of a matrix with rather complex entries and then determines the discriminant of that polynomial. For smaller matrices up to around 7x7 it finishes evaluating the Discriminant command within a few hours, but at a 10x10, which is what I need, it takes days to evaluate. Running in parallel won't work for the built in Discriminant command. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to evaluate the discriminant of high-order polynomial, as I know my code is basic.

```
    CPHH = Collect[CharacteristicPolynomial[HH, x],x]];
    DD = Discriminant[CPHH, x, Method -> SylvesterMatrix];
    Simplify[DD, TimeConstraint -> Infinity]
```

If the rest of the code would be useful in determining a solution I'd be happy to post it

Comment: Have you tried other methods? Or is this a case for which the Sylvester matrix is the only serious contender?

Comment: I've tried all other methods and SylvesterMatrix  is at least twice as  fast as BezoutMatrix, Subresultant, and Automatic for smaller matrices. For larger matrices the difference is even greater

Comment: What kind of entries does this matrix have? Integer, floating point, symbolic?

Comment: it has symbolic entries